# Alternative to JMF

Tags: java, image, webcam, jmf

I am using The Java Media Framework.

This framework is rather slow at processing images.

Please could you recommend a free framework for working with images that is fast enough to work and support high-resolution web-camera?

Comment: What exactly is slow about the processing you are doing?

Comment: @PaulWhelan The OP may have the full Java implementation installed rather than using native libraries, if not well then that's Java for you!

Comment: @PaulWhelan Thank you for correcting my question) Question translated by GoogleTranslate) With regards to the JMF, I got an image with a web-camera and displays it on the JPanel. The speed display was acceptable. If, after receiving images from a web-camera to move to 8-bit gray, and then take the result on the JPanel - then the video on JPanel significantly slows down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/)? It is a great Java alternative and uses FFmpeg as a backend. With good support and documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer) Connect to a web-camera with Xuggle - the video shows more smoothly, you can easily adjust the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Try [FMJ](http://www.fmj-sf.net/) . It is an open-source project with the goal of providing an alternative to Java Media Framework (JMF),

Comment: Just out of interest, have you managed to get FMJ working? Admittedly a while back, but I could never get the thing to work, and after talking with others I wasn't the only one...

Comment: Its been a while since ~ 5 years ago I did manage to get it working at the time @berry120

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I probably gave up a bit quickly :-)